# Check if camera or microphone is connected to computer

Tags: javascript, html, camera, microphone

I want to know weather camera/microphone is connected before calling `getUserMedia`. Is it possible? I could not google exact answer

Answer (score 1):

With current API is not possible, however the error callback function you pass to `getUserMedia` can be used to understand if the requested device is not available of the user denied the access to it.

Look at the specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#navigatorusermedia, especially the steps 15 and 16.